# Python Script/Programm to Search & Display an Image from Local Folder

Tags: python, database, image

I'm an absolute beginner in python and trying to build a script/programm that searches images from a folder by their name (meaning that it would need a search bar) and displays these image in the same window.

Think of it as sort of a phonebook where I have stored 100 names and pictures and I want to type in "Henry" to see Henry's picture.

On my search for a software that achieves this, I've come accross something similar:

```html
# img_viewer.py

import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os.path

# First the window layout in 2 columns

file_list_column = [
    [
        sg.Text("Image Folder"),
        sg.In(size=(25, 1), enable_events=True, key="-FOLDER-"),
        sg.FolderBrowse(),
    ],
    [
        sg.Listbox(
            values=[], enable_events=True, size=(40, 20), key="-FILE LIST-"
        )
    ],
]

# For now will only show the name of the file that was chosen
image_viewer_column = [
    [sg.Text("Choose an image from list on left:")],
    [sg.Text(size=(40, 1), key="-TOUT-")],
    [sg.Image(key="-IMAGE-")],
]

# ----- Full layout -----
layout = [
    [
        sg.Column(file_list_column),
        sg.VSeperator(),
        sg.Column(image_viewer_column),
    ]
]

window = sg.Window("Image Viewer", layout)

# Run the Event Loop
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    # Folder name was filled in, make a list of files in the folder
    if event == "-FOLDER-":
        folder = values["-FOLDER-"]
        try:
            # Get list of files in folder
            file_list = os.listdir(folder)
        except:
            file_list = []

        fnames = [
            f
            for f in file_list
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f))
            and f.lower().endswith((".png", ".gif"))
        ]
        window["-FILE LIST-"].update(fnames)
    elif event == "-FILE LIST-":  # A file was chosen from the listbox
        try:
            filename = os.path.join(
                values["-FOLDER-"], values["-FILE LIST-"][0]
            )
            window["-TOUT-"].update(filename)
            window["-IMAGE-"].update(filename=filename)

        except:
            pass

window.close()
```

This is almost perfect, but I would need to implement a search bar instead of clicking through the names as I will have ~20.000 entries and clicking through them is just not viable.

Any idea how I would go about achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Just one file after filtered not so good, My suggestion

1. Add one more `sg.InputText()` as filter for filename.ext
2. Event loop

   - Event for New holder or new filter

     - Get list of filenames of all files in folder, maybe also filtered by PNG, GIF.
     - Build new list to update 'sg.Listbox` if filter_string.lower() in filename_lower()
   - Event for listbox

     - Update `sg.Image` by clicked filename in listbox.

#### Update - Working sample code

[image]

```py
from pathlib import Path
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def update_listbox(listbox_element, folder, extension, substring):
    path = Path(folder)
    filter_ = substring.lower()
    lst = []
    if folder != '' and path.is_dir():
        files = list(path.glob("*.*"))
        lst = [file for file in files if file.suffix.lower() in extension
            and filter_ in str(file).lower() and file.is_file()]
    listbox_element.update(lst)

def update_image(image_element, filename):
    im = Image.open(filename)
    w, h = size_of_image
    scale = max(im.width/w, im.height/h)
    if scale <= 1:
        image_element.update(filename=filename)
    else:
        im = im.resize((int(im.width/scale), int(im.height/scale)),
            resample=Image.CUBIC)
        with BytesIO() as output:
            im.save(output, format="PNG")
            data = output.getvalue()
        image_element.update(data=data)

sg.theme('Dark')
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 11))

w, h = size_of_image = (700, 600)

layout_top = [
    [sg.InputText(enable_events=True, key='-FOLDER-'),
     sg.FolderBrowse('Browse', size=(7, 1), enable_events=True)],
    [sg.InputText(enable_events=True, key='-FILTER-'),
     sg.Button('Search', size=(7, 1))],
]
layout_bottom = [
    [sg.Listbox([], size=(52, 30), enable_events=True,
        select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE, key='-LISTBOX-')],
]
layout_left = [
    [sg.Column(layout_top, pad=(0, 0))],
    [sg.Column(layout_bottom, pad=(0, 0))],
]
layout_right = [[sg.Image(background_color='green', key='-IMAGE-')]]
layout = [
    [sg.Column(layout_left), sg.Column(layout_right, pad=(0, 0), size=(w+15, h+15), background_color='blue', key='-COLUMN-')],
]

window = sg.Window("PNG/GIF Viewer", layout, finalize=True)
window['-IMAGE-'].Widget.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
window['-IMAGE-'].Widget.master.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
window['-IMAGE-'].Widget.master.master.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
window['-COLUMN-'].Widget.pack_propagate(0)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    # print(event, values)
    if event in ('-FOLDER-', '-FILTER-', 'Search'):
        update_listbox(window['-LISTBOX-'], values['-FOLDER-'],
            ('.png', '.gif'), values['-FILTER-'])
    elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
        lst = values['-LISTBOX-']
        if lst != []:
            update_image(window['-IMAGE-'], values['-LISTBOX-'][0])

window.close()
```

Comment: Hey Jason! Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I don't quite know how to do achieve that. For example, where would I need to add the sg.inputtext()? And what does the event loop achieve? Thank you!

Comment: Hey Jason! That works wonderfully, thank you very much!!!